# lightdm отказ в работе

Tags: linux, debian, service, kali-linux, lightdm

lightdm работает только при первом запуске после полной переустановки системы. в консоли на повторную попытку запустить устройство (reboot) выдаёт:
[image: скриншот лога]

systemctl status lightdm:
[image: systemctl show lightdm]

система полностью чистая, а её переустановка даёт очень близкие к этому результаты (с разной периодичностью ломается). в основном после спящего режима hybrid sleep. настройки lightdm не клацал. всё по умолчанию. пытался установить accountsservice, после нескольких неудачных попыток запустить. не помогает. одну из errors убирает, но результат тот же. как исправить? куда смотреть?

Comment: Читайте логи в `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` или где-то в том районе

Comment: @andreymal а окей всё со строкой `Seat seat0 changes active session to ` (и пустота)? должно быть так? возможно, вы знаете на что можно обратить внимание, и что искать в логах `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`?